# How to reduce an array with duplicate value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, duplicates

I have an array like this

```
let oldArray=[
    {type:16,img:['1']},
    {type:16,img:['2']},
    {type:16,img:['3']},
    {type:17,img:['4']}
]
```

if the type is the same, i want to concat the value.
The result I want is:

```
let newArray=[
    {type:16,img:['1','2','3']},
    {type:17,img:['4']}
]
```

I tried to used reduce function:

```
    oldArray.reduce((acc,cur,idx,src)=>{
if(cur.type===a[idx+1].type){
    cur.img.concat(a[idx+1].img);
    acc.push(cur)
} else {
    acc.push(a[idx+1])
}
    return acc

},[])
```

It seems that there is an error
Can anyone help? Thanks.

---

Alternative to Bibberty's solution:flatMap is much clearer than reduce

```
let newArray = [...new Set(oldArray.map(e => e.type))]
                                    .map(e => {
                                        return {
                                            type: e,
                                            img: (oldArray.filter(i => i.type === e).map(x => x.img)).reduce((acc,cur,idx,src)=>{
                                                let length=src.length
                                                let tep=cur.concat(src[idx+1]);
                                                src[idx+1]=tep


                                                return src[idx=length-1]
                                            },[])
                                        }
                                    });

    console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Do  a search on how to do "groupBy" on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce`:

```js
let oldArray = [{type: 16,img: ['1']},{type: 16,img: ['2']},{type: 16,img: ['3']},{type: 17,img: ['4']}];

let newArray = oldArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.some(({
    type
  }) => type == curr.type) ? acc.find(({
    type
  }) => type == curr.type).img.push(curr.img[0]) : acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: this solution uses the least amount of code and very easy to follow and understand. This is what i am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @MINGWU, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

We use a Set and then a map.

The Set is populate with the unique types by using a map to extract. 
We wrap in `[]` to give us an array the we then re `map` to build our object back. 
The map then rebuilds our objects and note the use of `filter` and `map` to get the `img` values from the original host array.

```js
let oldArray=[
    {type:16,img:['1']},
    {type:16,img:['2']},
    {type:16,img:['3']},
    {type:17,img:['4']}
]

let newArray = [...new Set(oldArray.map(e => e.type))]
                .map(e => {
                  return {
                    type: e,
                    img: oldArray.filter(i => i.type === e).flatMap(x => x.img)
                  }
                });
  
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Hi Bibberty, thanks for your answer. However, the result is a little bit different from the one I want. From your result, the image is    "img":[  ['1'],['2'],['3'] ] . I want 'img':['1','2','3']. Your solution really inspired me and i added a reduce function on top of your function.Thanks.

Comment: Corrected to what you need, just added `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not a reduce but return result you are looking for is the same

```js
let oldArray = [
    {type:16,img:['1']},
    {type:16,img:['2']},
    {type:16,img:['3']},
    {type:17,img:['4']}
];

const transitoryMap = new Map();
for (const item of oldArray) {
    if (!transitoryMap.has(item.type)) {
        transitoryMap.set(item.type, [item.img[0]])
    } else {
        const value = transitoryMap.get(item.type)
        value.push(item.img[0])
        transitoryMap.set(item.type, value)
    }
}
    
const newArray = [];
for (const item of transitoryMap.keys()) {
    newArray.push({type:item,img:transitoryMap.get(item)})
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `reduce`. I have added a `tracker` to keep track of type in the `newArray`.

```js
let oldArray = [
    {type:16,img:['1']},
    {type:16,img:['2']},
    {type:16,img:['3']},
    {type:17,img:['4']}
];

oldArray.reduce((a,c)=>{
    let index = a.tracker.indexOf(c.type);
    if(index === -1) {
        a.tracker.push(c.type);
        a.newArray.push({...c, img:[...c.img]});
    } else {
        a.newArray[index].img.push(...c.img);
    }
    return a;
},{tracker:[],newArray:[]}).newArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider breaking up the processing into separate simple steps, for example:

1. Create a flattened object with the appropriate data.
2. build a new array with the wanted structure.

This will not only keep your code simple, but will allow you to focus on what your code is actually doing instead of how it is doing the task.

```
var oldArray=[
    {type:16,img:['1']},
    {type:16,img:['2']},
    {type:16,img:['3']},
    {type:17,img:['4']}
]

flattenMyObject = (arr) =>
    arr.reduce((accum, current) => {
        !!accum[current.type] ? accum[current.type].push(...current.img) : accum[current.type] = current.img;
        return accum;
    }, {});

buildNewArray = (type) => {
    return {type: type, img: flattenedObject[type] }
}

Object
  .keys(flattenMyObject(oldArray))
  .map(buildNewArray);
```